# cannot load such file -- prawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have installed the prawn gem, also added it in Gemfile of my project and den install bundles. After installing the bundles I have added this line "Mime::Type.register "application/pdf", :pdf" in my mim-type.rb file. I have added following code in my controller but giving error of "cannot load such file -- prawn". Please guide where I m wrong or missing something? I am new to ruby on rails.Thanks in advance...

```
   def pdf_test
    require "prawn"
    Prawn::Document.generate("hello.pdf") do
      text "Hello World!"
    end
   end
```

Comment: did you restarted your server after doing all this ?

Comment: After restarting server also i m getting same error

Comment: what is the output of  `bundle show prawn` ?

Answer (score 1):

In rails, no need to require gems specified in gemfile. All gems will be automatically required in `application.rb`.